# Java: Determine type of KeyStore from Keystore file

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, keystore

So I have an application in which I'm allowing the user to configure the server with HTTPS. The server uses Undertow. To add a HTTPS handler to Undertow, I need to make a call to Keystore.getInstance("JKS") function which returns the implementation based on the provider. Java natively supports only 3 providers(JKS, PKCS12 and JCEKS) but from my understanding, you can add your own provider of Keystore implementation.

So my question is, given just the keystore file, is it possible to determine what type of Keystore it is? I cannot rely on file extension as PKCS12 keystores can be stored in .p12 file extension as well. Is there I can get this value programmatically so that I can pass it to Keystore.getInstance() or do I have to just take that input from the user?

Comment: `Keystore.getInstance("JKS") function which returns the implementation based on the provider`: no it doesn't. It returns a KeyStore of type JKS. If this is the method call you need to make, you don't have a problem. If you do have the problem, you need the argument to be a variable. I wouldn't worry about the user supplying their own provider.

Comment: @user207421 I meant that as an example. I either have to find out the type of keystore from the file and call the getInstance method, or expose it as an input to the user. Preferably the first.

Comment: Example of what exactly? And in general you can't do the first, can you? You just have to try all known providers, or have the user tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in WildFly there is in progress such feature using Elytron project. You can have a look [1].

Some of keystores can be distinguished by format pattern. But I think in your case easiest is to try to load one by one Keystore.getInstance("PKCS12"), Keystore.getInstance("JKS"), Keystore.getInstance("JCEKS") and see which one passes.

Also I think user will be ok with providing keystore type.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-4058

Comment: Loading one by one and seeing if it works is okay if there are only 3 types. There are other providers as well with custom Keystore implementations. So this solution cannot cover all possible implementations.